# The minimum codimension of Lie subalgebra of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Assume that $M$ is an arbitrary manifold.

> Is there a Lie subalgebra of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$, the space of smooth vector fields on $M$, whose codimension is equal to one?

If not, what is a counter example?

In particular what is the answer to this question for $M=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or $M=S^{2}$?

The  question is a particular case of the following general question:

**Question: For a $n$ dimensional manifold $M$, is it true to say that the minimal  codimension of  Lie  sub algebras of  $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ is equal to $n$?**

The above question serachs for obstruction for finite codimensionality of Lie subalgebras  (codimension equal to one) of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ while the following post concerns diversity and variation of finite dimensional Lie subalgebras.

[A Manifold for which $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ is rich](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160449/a-manifold-for-which-chi-inftym-is-rich?rq=1)

Comment: Explain the notation please. Does it mean the smooth vector fields?

Comment: @BenMcKay yes I mean the space of smooth vector fields.I revise it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be a sub-algebra of $\mathrm{Vect}(M)$. I think one might be able to prove $\mathrm{codim}\  L \geq \dim M$ by using a recent result of [Hurtado](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.4447). Here is a sketch of the proposed proof, every step of which is difficult:

(1) Let $G \subset \mathrm{Diff}(M)$ be the group generated by $\exp(L)$. **Problem:** The exponential need not converge.

(2) Let $N = \mathrm{Diff}(M)/G$. One hopes that $N$ is a manifold of dimension $\mathrm{codim}(L)$. **Problem** It is not clear how to put a manifold structure on $N$.

We then get a homomorphism $\mathrm{Diff}(M) \to \mathrm{Diff}(N)$ by the action of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ on the quotient $N$. Hurtado shows that such maps only exist if $\dim M \leq \dim N$.

---

We can, at least momentarily, dodge discussions of quotients and exponentials of infinite dimensional Lie groups by defining $N$ to be be the set of subalgebras of $\mathrm{Vect}(M)$ conjugate to $L$ by an element of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ (or perhaps $\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$.)

Hopefully, the set of all codimension $n$ subspaces of $\mathrm{Vect}(M)$ is some sort of manifold by a Grassmannian like construction, and then $N$ can be a closed submanifold of this. If we are lucky, then the tangent space to $N$ at $[L]$ is $\mathrm{Vect}(M)/L$.

We clearly have a map $\mathrm{Diff}(M) \to \mathrm{Bijections}(N)$ and, presumably, once we have built the smooth structure on $N$ this will be a map $\mathrm{Diff}(M) \to \mathrm{Diff}(N)$ and Hurtado's result will tell us that $\dim M \leq \dim N = \dim(\mathrm{Vect}(M)/L)$.

All of this needs to come with the disclaimer that I am a simple minded algebraic geometer, who doesn't like these infinite dimensional objects.

Comment: Thank you very  much for  your  elegant strategy. May be the extra assumption "L is  an ideal " makes some facilities?

Comment: The second step seems fishy, even in finite dimensions; if we integrate an irrational line in $\Bbb R^2$ to a subgroup in the torus, it needn't be closed, so we don't get a manifold structure on the quotient.

Comment: @MikeMiller Agreed. I was actually thinking of coming back today to remark on this. There are a few ways we could try to get around this: (1) restrict to cases where $\pi_1(\mathrm{Diff}(M))$ is trivial (2) replace $\exp(L)$ by its closure (but then we have to argue that its closure isn't the whole group) (3) See if Hurtado's proof adapts to the universal cover of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer  What  about the  following alternative opposit approach for compact  symplectic  manifold $(M, \omega)$ with  volum form $\Omega=\omega^{n}$:

Comment: 1)Is the space $S$ of all $f$ with $\int_{M} fd\Omega =0$ a  Lie  algebra (with poisson structure on $C^{\infty}(M)$? \new line 2) Is there  a  non zero   Lie  algebra morphism from $\chi^{\infty}(M) $ to $C^{\infty}(M)$? Is there  a Lie  algebra  Morphism whose  image is  not  contained in the above  $S$. If the  answers to the above questions would  be  positive then we  have  a  codimension one  Lie  subalgebra of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$.

Comment: On a side note, if one solves the first two problems, you've actually proved not only that the minimum codimension of a subalgebra is $n$, but also that all codimension $n$ subalgebras are these $L_p$. Hurtado shows that when $m=n$, the homomorphism is of the form "Lift a diffeomorphism of $M$ to a diffeomorphism of $N$ through a covering map $p: N \to M$." By your construction, the homomorphism sends $L$ to one of the $L_p$ in $\text{Diff}(N)$ (specifically, to $L_{[G]}$.)

Comment: Your space $S$ is a subalgebra: The Poisson algebra $C^{\infty}(M)$ (for $M$ symplectic, compact, connected) always splits as the direct sum $\mathbb{R} \oplus S$. But I can't think of a map $\mathrm{Vect}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$ which doesn't land in $S$. (If $M$ is Riemmannian, then we have $\mathrm{Vect}(M) \cong \Omega^1(M) \overset{d^{\ast}}{\longrightarrow} C^{\infty}(M)$, but, at least if the Riemannian structure gives the same volume form as the symplectic one, the image of $d^{\ast}$ lands in $S$. And I have no idea if this is a map of Lie algebras anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

Let $M=S^1=\mathbb R/2\pi \mathbb Z$. Then $\mathfrak X^\infty(M) = \{ f\partial_\theta: f\in C^\infty(M)\}$. Fix a point $\theta_0\in S^1$. The subalgebra $\{f\partial_\theta: f\in C^\infty(S^1): f(\theta_0)=0\}$ has codimension 1. The corresponding Lie subgroup is the group of all diffeomorphisms which fix $\theta_0$.

Comment: Prof. Michor thank you for your answer. I think  for every n dim manifold there is a codimension n subliealgebra consist all vector fields vanishing at a given point p.But in my question I did not assume any restriction on M. So I rwvise the question.